# Loop over webpages (like google search) while webscraping in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I am trying scraping a real estate site. The scraping code is working good, but I have a problem:

When I do a research in this site (that looks like google) it shows me a lot of pages.

How can I count how many pages the search found and than **scrape** all of them?

The site is: https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/aluguel/predio-inteiro/?transacao=Aluguel&tipoUnidade=Comercial,Pr%C3%A9dio%20Inteiro&tipo=Im%C3%B3vel%20usado

As you can see, when I do a simple search it shows me on top:

"10.177 prédios inteiros para alugar" which means "10.177 building available for rental".

In the bottom the site shows some pages found, I wanna **scrape** over all of them.

here is my code, I have to **scrape** like below each page of the search.. its working for scraping data like Rent, Square Meters:

````
import pandas as pd 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}

url = requests.get("https://www.zapimoveis.com.br/aluguel/predio-inteiro/?transacao=Aluguel&tipoUnidade=Comercial,Pr%C3%A9dio%20Inteiro&tipo=Im%C3%B3vel%20usado", headers = headers)

if url.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")

Aluguel = [headline.get_text() for headline in soup.find_all("p", {"class": "simple-card__price"})]

AluguelFixed = list(map(int, [i.replace('.', '').replace("R$", "").replace("mês", "").replace("\n","").replace("/","").strip() for i in Aluguel]))

Metragem = [li.find("span", recursive=False).get_text() for li in soup.find_all("li", {"class": "feature__item" }) ]

MetragemAjustada = list(map(int, [i.replace('m²', '').strip() for i in Metragem if 'm²' in i]))

BancoDeDados = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1": MetragemAjustada, "col2": AluguelFixed})

BancoDeDados.to_csv("C:\\Users\\fernando.rezende\\OneDrive - ES Ltda\\Área de Trabalho/RobozapDataFrame.csv", sep=',',index=False) ```
````

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the issue, exactly? Are you familiar with the basics of web scraping, and how to go about doing so? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC When I do a search, the site shows me a lot of pages (like google). I wanna know how to make a loop all over this pages. I have no idea how to find the number of pages or the links... The scrapping code is working fine (as above) just need to find out how to loop all the pages after a search.. Hope I was more clear.. thanks for helping

Comment: You might be able to find a link on the page to the next one. You would scrape the contents of that new page, find the link to the 3rd page, and so on. It’s also possible that the link isn’t in the HTML, but you can build it yourself quite easily.

Comment: @AMC i looked the entire HTML  but there is no links. There is a button ( > ) to move to next page. If I could click on it then my problem would be solved.. I´m searching some selenium using driver.   I built all the links by myself but I have more than 30K links.. And some doesn´t work, looks like there are a lot of differente links in the site.

Comment: _I´m searching some selenium using driver. I built all the links by myself but I have more than 30K links.._ I'm not sure I understand what you mean, can you explain things further?

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap